# How to visual a 3D bathymetry data in Paraview

Tags: visualization, netcdf, paraview

I want to display a 3D bathymetry data in paraview, the file datatype is netcdf:
it has two dimensions and three variables;
[my netcdf file format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPZ9m.png)

When I try to open it in paraview: it is a 2D not 3D,
[2D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YKP0.png)
 I want to display Dlike this:
[3D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2mlY.png)
i’m sorry for bad English and less infomation.

Comment: please share your file.

Comment: this is a small file,(2mb),Thanks a Ton. https://www.dropbox.com/s/f6mptbtcqmokj0o/GEBCO_2019_131.0_35.0_134.0_32.0.nc?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple way to do that is to use the Extrusion Surface representation.
https://blog.kitware.com/a-new-embossing-representations-plugin-for-paraview/

- Open ParaView
- Tools -> Manage Plugins -> Embossing Representations
- Create a new view
- Open your file
- Switch representation to Extrusion Surface

[image]

Only Available since ParaView 5.6.0. Keep in mind this is only a representation, not a change to the actual data. If you want to change the data, you will have to use CellDataToPointData and WarpByScalar, which will require more tweaking.

Comment: Wow!, I get it !  That's very kind of you.